# How do I add new MODULE in MS DYNAMICS CRM 2013 TRIAL VERSION?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to add new module 'Project' on MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Tril Version.

by Default I can see Sales, Services and Marketing. How can I add new scenario "Project Tracker" next to those 3 existed scenario?

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will need to edit the Sitemap.xml to add a new `<Area></Area>` section.

For the step-by-step details of how to export/edit/import the Sitemap visit: http://blog.allegient.com/blog/changing-those-pesky-tiles-in-the-crm-2013-menu-bar

This images below from the blog show how you would add a new Area.

[image: Credit for image to blog.allegient.com]

[image: Credit for image to blog.allegient.com]

I recommend, as does the referenced blog article, using the Sitemap Editor in XRMToolbox (http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/) which makes the process very simple - the tool eliminates the need to 
edit XML or manually import/export.